# how to give docusign connect listener page?

Tags: docusignapi

In docusign connect url can i give js file like http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/index.js 
or only with server side scripting.how to give docusign connect listener page?

Answer (score 1):

You can supply any url that you like to the [DocuSign Connect API](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect).

You can also supply a url as the [Envelope Event Notification parameter](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm). It enables you to register your Web Hook URL as part of the envelope send method.

In both cases you are supplying a "web hook" url--your url will be called by the DocuSign DTM platform. This means that your url must be visible on the public internet.

If your url is behind a firewall, then you must have an opening in the firewall to enable DocuSign to call the url.

The software behind your url can be written in any language. It can't be a static web page, it needs to be a page that can receive and process the information it receives from DocuSign.

As an alternative to writing your own "listener," check out the [DocuSign Retrieve product](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/retrieve-quick-start-guide.pdf).